# Dia de la semana a partir de fecha en formato int

Tags: java, date, calendar

Quiero que hacer una función que a partir de tres valores en int (dia mes año) me devuelva que dia de la semana es, googleando he llegado a esta funcion pero me da error, no acierta con el dia que es.

Este es el código:

```
   String diaSemana (int dia, int mes, int ano)
   {
    String letraD="";
    int nD =-1;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.set(ano, mes, dia);
    nD=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
    switch (nD){
        case 1: letraD = "D";
            break;
        case 2: letraD = "L";
            break;
        case 3: letraD = "M";
            break;
        case 4: letraD = "X";
            break;
        case 5: letraD = "J";
            break;
        case 6: letraD = "V";
            break;
        case 7: letraD = "S";
            break;
    }

    return letraD;
}
```

Dejo aqui un log.i que tengo para depurar:
diaSemana: 4               2017,4,10
deberia salir dia semana: 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os pongo la solucion que he encontrado
He usado GregorianCalendar finalmente y he tenido que restar uno al mes (Enero es mes 0) . Este es el código:

```
String diaSemana (int dia, int mes, int ano)
    {
        String letraD="";
        /*Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(ano, mes, dia, 0, 0, 0);
        nD=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);*/
        TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(timezone);
        calendar.set(ano, mes-1, dia);
        int nD=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        Log.i("result","diaSemana: "+nD+" dia:"+dia+" mes:"+mes+ "año:" +ano);
        switch (nD){
            case 1: letraD = "D";
                break;
            case 2: letraD = "L";
                break;
            case 3: letraD = "M";
                break;
            case 4: letraD = "X";
                break;
            case 5: letraD = "J";
                break;
            case 6: letraD = "V";
                break;
            case 7: letraD = "S";
                break;
        }

        return letraD;
    }
```

También he encontrado esta que es mas sencilla e intuitiva:

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.set(año,mes,dia) // vairables int
 int dia =  c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
 if(dia==Calendar.SUNDAY){
   //Domingo
 }if(dia==Calendar.MONDAY){
   //Lunes
 }
if(dia==Calendar.TUESDAY){
   //Martes
 }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Que tal Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
public class TryDateFormats 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException 
   {       
        String month = "08";
        String day = "05";
        String year = "2015";
        String inputDateStr = String.format("%s/%s/%s", day, month, year);
        Date inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(inputDateStr);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(inputDate);
        String dayOfWeek = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US).toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, he editado el Post, mi idea es seguir con el int, ya no me da el error pero me dice que es martes cuando es lunes y asi

Answer (score 1):

El 1 es domingo y el de mes enero.

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

```
c.set(2017, 3, 1); //año, mes, día  


        int diaSemana = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (diaSemana == 1) {
            Valor_dia = "Domingo";
        } else if (diaSemana == 2) {
            Valor_dia = "Lunes";
        } else if (diaSemana == 3) {
            Valor_dia = "Martes";
        } else if (diaSemana == 4) {
            Valor_dia = "Miercoles";
        } else if (diaSemana == 5) {
            Valor_dia = "Jueves";
        } else if (diaSemana == 6) {
            Valor_dia = "Viernes";
        } else if (diaSemana == 7) {
            Valor_dia = "Sabado";
        }
        return Valor_dia;
        }
```

Comment: he editado el post cambiado el switch para que uno sea domingo y asi sucesivamente, me sigue devolviendo mal el dia

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema esta en la linea siguiente:
c.set(ano, mes, dia);

El metodo 
public final void set(int year,
       int month,
       int date)

Establece los valores para los campos del objeto calendario, sin embargo, para el valor del mes, este inicia desde 0. por ejemplo, 0 para identificar el mes de enero.

Por lo que la solucion seria poner un -1 al valor del mes, cuando se invoca el metodo set.

```
public static String diaSemana(int mes, int dias, int año) {
         String dia="";
         int numD;
         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
         c.set(año,mes-1,dias);
         numD=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if(numD == Calendar.SUNDAY)
            dia="DOMINGO";
        else if(numD == Calendar.MONDAY)
            dia="LUNES";
        else if(numD == Calendar.TUESDAY)
            dia="MARTES";
        else if(numD == Calendar.WEDNESDAY)
            dia="MIERCOLES";
        else if(numD == Calendar.THURSDAY)
            dia="JUEVES";
        else if(numD == Calendar.FRIDAY)
            dia="VIERNES";
        else if(numD == Calendar.SATURDAY)
            dia="SABADO";
         return dia;
    }
}
```

Igual podria ser con un Switch.

Fuente de informacion consultada:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int)